# How to install postgresql in already created Rails app on Mac?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I'm new here and just installed ruby on rails on my mach using  this tutorial.

I created a project folder and added an app to it.

Now I want to use postgresql, how do I install that in this created app... that is something I can't figure out.

I think I need to install Postgresql first.

Is the best way to do it form command line like this:
brew install postgresql

or

go to their website and download/install?

Remember I'm totally new to this so help is appreciated a lot

Thanks

EDIT: So I downloaded postgresql and installed it and I downloaded and installed pgadmin.

What's next is probably I have to create a database? and then somehow find a way to connect it with the application created in the workspace for ruby?

Answer (score 1):

Postgres.app is great and has become the go-to for many Mac developers.

https://postgresapp.com/

Comment: I went there, dowloaded, installed it following points 1-3

Then in How to connect I chose Ruby and installed pg gem

Comment: The sections below that are the files where to add a db name of course so nothing to do in terminal with that I suppose.


How do I create a postgress db now for an application I just created in the terminal for Rails?


I created a workspace folder, in that folder I created a new rails application... no the only thing left is to have a postgresql db assigned to that


I must be missing something in my brain that keeps me from understanding the next step

Comment: It sounds like you're new to Rails. You should consult http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html for the basics of how to use Ruby on Rails. There's many, many guides available that show you how to do just that, and aren't limited to the characters I have available in this input field.